# Duplicate pairs in an array

Tags: python, arrays, count

Given an array A with zero index and N integers find equal elements with different positions in the array. Pair of indexes `(P,Q)` such that `0 <= P < Q < N` such that `A[P] = A[Q]`.

My idea:

```
def function(arr, n) :  
    count = 0
    arr.sort()
    i = 0
    while i < (n-1) :  
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) : 
            count += 1
            i = i + 2
        else : 
            i += 1 
  
    return count
```

Two questions:

1. How do I avoid counting elements whose first indices are not smaller than the second indices?
2. How do I build a function where the input is only the array? (So not (arr, n))

Comment: is arr like `[1,2]` or `[[1,2],[3,4]]`?

Comment: @AnnZen The array consists of N integers, so I assume the first option?

Comment: as for 2., simply use `len(arr)` whenever you need `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is similar to this:

This one is the naive approach:

```
def function(arr) :  
    count = 0
    n = len(arr)
    i = 0
    for i in range(n):
      for j in range(i+1,n):
        if arr[i]==arr[j]:
          count+=1
    return count
```

This one is more optimized approach you can try:

```
def function(arr) :  
    mp = dict() 
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n): 
        if arr[i] in mp.keys(): 
            mp[arr[i]] += 1
        else: 
            mp[arr[i]] = 1

    ans = 0
    for it in mp: 
        count = mp[it] 
        ans += (count * (count - 1)) // 2
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurrences of every integer,
then use [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) with `n=count` and `k=2` to get the number of such pairs for every integer, and simply sum them:

```py
from collections import Counter
from math import comb

def function(arr):
    return sum(comb(count, 2) for num,count in Counter(arr).items())

print(function([1,2,3,6,3,6,3,2]))
```

The reason `math.comb(count,2)` is exactly the number of pairs is that any `2` elements out of the `count` you choose, **regardless of their order**, are a single pair: the former one is `P` and the latter is `Q`.

---

**EDIT: Added `timeit` benchmakrs**:

Here's a full example you can test to compare the performance of both methods:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from random import randint
from collections import Counter
from math import comb

def with_comb(arr):
    return sum(comb(count, 2) for num,count in Counter(arr).items())

def with_loops(arr):
    mp = dict()
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i] in mp.keys():
            mp[arr[i]] += 1
        else:
            mp[arr[i]] = 1

    ans = 0
    for it in mp:
        count = mp[it]
        ans += (count * (count - 1)) // 2
    return ans

a = [randint(1,1000) for _ in range(10000)]

time1 = timeit('with_loops(a)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
time2 = timeit('with_comb(a)', globals=globals(), number=1000)

print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time1/time2)
```

Output (on my laptop):

```
2.9549962
0.8175686999999998
3.6143705110041524
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that too but I am stuck because of a really silly question: how optimal is this compared to the second approach proposed by @gagangaur above?

Comment: @a0142204 see my benchmark (and try running it yourself, I guess), on my laptop it seems like my method rund x3.6 times faster.

Comment: @a0142204 on repl.it it seems to be rouglhy the same (even x4.1): https://repl.it/repls/LegalGlassUpgrade#main.py